# How to get the first item and the last item in a single sql statement

Tags: mysql, sql

I was wondering how to grab the first item and the last item in a MySQL database. I know these two lines will do the work, but I am trying to limit it down to one line.

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` order by ID asc limit 0,1
SELECT * FROM `test_table` order by ID desc limit 0,1
```

For example there is a table called `test_table` and it has 5 rows. I would like to get row number 1 and row number 5 in the same statement. This will save me from using many PHP if statements and will shorten up my code. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following SQL does *not* get the first item:

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` limit 0,1
```

It returns an *arbitrary* row.  SQL tables and result sets are *unordered*, so `limit` without `order by` returns an indeterminate row.

The syntax to do what you want is:

```
(SELECT t.* FROM `test_table` t ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 1)
UNION ALL
(SELECT t.* FROM `test_table` t ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1);
```

Note:  If the table has only one row, this returns two rows, because the same row is the "first" and "last".  If you want only one in this situation, you could use `UNION` rather than `UNION ALL`.

Comment: Thank you, this answers my question.

Answer (score 1):

use `union` it will combine both sql queries and you the expected result

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table` limit 0,1
union
SELECT * FROM `test_table` order by ID desc limit 0,1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the min and max ID if it's monotonically increasing -

```
SELECT * FROM `test_table`
WHERE ID IN ((SELECT MIN(ID) FROM `test_table`), (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM `test_table`));
```

I'd suggest running the explain for the query to see if it performs as per your expectation.

Comment: This did work and successfully grabbed the first and last rows of the table, Thank You.